# Change navigationController backButton title in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to change the navigation controller's back button title and couldn't do it so far.
I am building an app that can change the UI language with a UISegmentedControl.
I created a model, and when we change the language in the segmented control it triggers the method that makes the UI conform to the model (inside the model the language is set).
The code works fine for everything but the backButton title. I have tried different ways of accessing it. The current one is:
[The way I am trying to modify it now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHWBO.png)

I also tried:

```
self.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = model.navigationBackButtonTitle
```

and

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = model.navigationBackButtonTitle
```

and even

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = model.navigationBackButtonTitle
```

I am starting in development and trying to change careers, so forgive me if I am asking something wrong. I hope you guys can help me out.

PS.: I was able to modify the back button color in another method using the code below.
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = buttonColor

Comment: what's the type of self here ? 
is it UINavigationController?

Comment: self is UIViewController in this case @RaghavKundra.

Comment: simply saying, self.navigationItem is a property on UIViewController and what you want to do is self.navigationController?.navigationItem.
should work the way you are changing in tintColor of backBarButtonItem.
self.navigationController?.navigationItem?.title = model.navigationBackButtonTitle

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RaghavKundra. I just tried to do it that way as you said, but I am getting the same result. The backButton title still appears "Back", while it should change to "Voltar" in Portuguese when I change the language. Is there something that can block the title change?

Comment: @RaghavKundra thank you for your help. I found a way. if we use: navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.title we can change the title. I think the problem was that I was trying to modify the bar button title for the current View Controller, and from what I have seen in the Documentation, it would just appear in the current View Controller's child if I understood it right. But it makes sense since when modified the title on the navigation bar, it  worked.